# In Flux, is it kosher to have generic components call the ActionCreator?

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux

Most of the Flux documentation I've found is lacking in the discussion of Components vs. Containers.

I know that it's considered best practice to have containers as the sole elements responsible for listening to the stores.  This absolutely makes sense because;

1. It limits the number of components listening to the stores.
2. Child components have a single place (their props) to receive data from.

But some explanations imply that Containers should also be responsible for all calls to the ActionCreator.  And on that point, I'm not really seeing the advantages.

Convince me I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** My only experience with Flux comes from Redux, which isn't quite the same pattern - that said, I believe the concept is the same either way.

Effectively, the reasoning behind having the container call the action creators is the same as the reasoning for passing data through the props instead of just having every component listening to the store - it means that your presentational components don't need to know anything about the world around them.

Take the (completely original and not overdone in the slightest) example of a Todo list app. You *could* hard-code that clicking a `TodoItem` fires a `CompleteTodo` action - but then if I want to display a read-only version of the item elsewhere in my app, I'd have to make another version of the component that doesn't call that action creator. If you pass a callback that calls the action creator in as an optional prop instead, the item no longer has to manage what happens when it's clicked - it just has to tell the parent when it happens, then the parent is free to do what it wants with that information, or even ignore it entirely.

It's not a perfect example, but hopefully it illustrates the reason why some people recommend doing it that way!